# Tools enabling text formatting an syntax highlighting rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been looking for tools that woul enable me to add text formatting an syntax higlighting  to a text area. I want to get somethiing like "StackOverflow", i mean buttons to highlight code, other buttons to a items, to make a selecte text italic or bold...etc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). It is extremely easy to use and pretty well documented. You may get it via [this gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor).

Comment: Does it enable syntax highlighting?

Comment: There is a number of plugins for CKEditor, one of them is: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/SyntaxHighlighter-v3

Comment: Thans, but is it integrated in the gem?

Comment: It is not, you will need to download it and add it into a CKEditor config.

Answer (score 0):

U mean **Text editor**, TinyMce is also good to go [see here](http://www.tinymce.com/), UI is good, and Insert image/files is not freely available, demo is also available in try it section..

Comment: But this doesn't enable syntax highlighting for source code